# Whats the best way to create short URL's

Tags: url

I have a client that wants to create a short URL to an entry for a mail shot. What would be the best way to do this. I have the [Reroute plugin](http://viget.com/extend/reroute-plugin-for-craft) installed which would work (setting to a 302 redirect) but I am wondering if that is the best approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a plugin that generates a short URL using a link-shortener API (e.g. [dev.bitly](http://dev.bitly.com/code_libraries.html)) for each of your entries and provides the URL as a custom read-only Field Type.

Comment: Hi carlcs, thank you for your answer. They want to keep their domain name rather than use a service. So all that's required is changing `example.com/some/long/url/structure` to `example.com/some` short. I should have made that clear in the question sorry.

Comment: Yah, in this case your plugin is probably the best solution, @Gareth. If it is not enough, you could look into modifying it to (automatically) set up that routes from Edit Entry pages.